# Are compact and Hausdorff subsets closed if the topology is determined by them?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space such that

$$\mathcal{T} = \{U \subset X : \forall C \in P(\mathcal{T}): U \cap C \in \mathcal{T}|C\},$$

where $P(\mathcal{T})$ is the set of all compact-and-Hausdorff subsets of $X$ and $\mathcal{T}|C$ denotes the subspace topology in $C$.

Are the sets in $P(\mathcal{T})$ closed?

Comment: Not sure how much this helps, but one can prove that $X$ is $T_1$. So, if there are any counterexample it must be $T_1$ but not Hausdorff.

Comment: I wonder why someone voted to close.

Comment: I think the question is fine and interesting, but the person who voted to close seemed to feel that the question needs more motivating details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe not. Consider a converging sequence with two limit points. Then the infinite compact Hausdorff subsets are given by cofinal subsequences with a single limit point, which are not closed in the space. But they determine the topology: sets here are open if they avoid both limit points, or they contain a final subsequence.

Comment: Nice. A concrete example is to take the $\{0, 0^*\} \cup \{1/n : n \in \mathbb{N}^{> 0}\}$ subspace of the line with two origins. I actually considered this before, but made some thinking error, and discarded it.